# What is the difference between being generated as a field and being generated as a k-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to understand why given an infinite field $\mathbb{k}$, $\mathbb{k}[t]$ the field of rational functions in one variable is finitely generated as a field, but not as an algebra over $\mathbb{k}$.

What does it mean "being finitely generated as a field"?

Comment: In a field you allow division

Comment: Compare $\mathbb Q(x)$ and $\mathbb Q[x]$. The former is a 2-generated field, the latter is a 1-generated $\mathbb Q$-algebra.

Comment: Given a field extension $F / G$, $F$ is finitely generated over $G$ iff there are $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in G$ such that the only subfield of $F$ which contains $G$ and also $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is $F$ itself. Given a ring map $i : G \to F$, $F$ is a finitely generated $G$-algebra iff there are $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ such that the only subalgebra of $F$ containing $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is $F$ itself. These are clearly different statements a priori.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial algebra $\Bbb k[x]$ is (freely) generated by the single element $x$ as a $\Bbb k$-algebra.

Similarly, the field $\Bbb k(t)$ is generated by a single transcendent $t$ over $\Bbb k$.

However, as a $\Bbb k$-algebra it is not finitely generated:
Consider any finite list of rational functions $r_i:=f_i(t)/g_i(t)$, and take an element $a\in\Bbb k$ that is not a root of any of $g_i$'s.
Then, all the elements of the subalgebra generated by $r_i$ only have products of $g_i(t)$ in the denominator, so $\frac1{t-a}$ is not among them.